# Expanding macros for debugging?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to using macro functions and I understand there are some pitfalls in their use when it comes to order of operations. Is there a way to expand the macro after the preprocessor goes through it so I can see what it looks like?

In VS2017, I've tried Processor > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocess to a file which creates an `*.i` file but it's around 50k lines long and I can't seem to find where my macro was expanded to.

edit: I know macros are bad news bears, however, the code base I'm stepping into uses them quite a bit so I'm trying to better understand them.

Comment: If you expand macros, you will get a lot of code to look at - one of many reasons that you should not be using macros, at least in C++.

Comment: Understood - unfortunately, the code base I've stepped into uses them so I'm trying to figure out how to understand them.

Comment: I you are using an `IDE` like *eclipse* you can just hover over the macro and it gets expanded in a popup window.

Comment: I'm using VS2017, when I hover over the macro it just tells me what I see.

Comment: Adding to @Galik's comment - you can see the expansions step-by-step and then understand the order.

Comment: Some compilers have a command line switch that allows dumping of the preprocessed source files.  Check the options for your compiler.

Comment: The option to create that `.i` file is probably the best you're going to get.  But: search is your friend!  Read the file into a good text editor, and search for some keywords or function calls which you know to be near by to the macro expansion you're interested in, and you should be able to find it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews They already tried that, "but it's around 50k lines long and I can't seem to find where my macro was expanded to."

Comment: "I'm new to using macro functions" - then learn this right now: *don't* use macros at all (except in the very few situations where they really/unfortunately are the only option).

Comment: @Steve Summit - Sure. I was just providing general advice. And even inherited macros can usually, in many cases, be re-written as proper functions ;-)

Comment: @Steve Summit In my book blunt == good. I was just trying to nail down the point of *don't use macros*.

Comment: Alternatively, you can right-click on the macro and choose "Go to Definition", then use that to expand the macro by hand.  Not quite the same thing as what you're asking for, but it can be useful if you're working with macros you can't change (assuming Visual Studio) can find where they're defined!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In VS2017, I've tried Processor > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocess to a file which creates an *.i file but it's around 50k lines long and I can't seem to find where my macro was expanded to.

You can help yourself by declaring a dummy variable before the line where a macro is used.

E.g.

```
extern int dummyIntVariable;
MY_COMPLICATED_MACRO(arg1, arg2);
```

After that, you look for `dummyIntVariable` in the .i file. The line below it will contain what `MY_COMPLICATED_MACRO` expands to.

Or as @Sneftel pointed out in a comment, you can use any old string that helps you navigate through the .i file.

```
THIS IS A UNIQUE STRING
MY_COMPLICATED_MACRO(arg1, arg2);
```

Since the file will be just pre-processed, that should also work.

Comment: If you're only preprocessing, you don't even have to declare the dummy variable.

Comment: @Sneftel, The dummy variable is useful for navigating through the 50k lines the OP sees in the .i file.

Comment: No, I mean, the code doesn't need to compile, just preprocess. You can just put `THIS IS A UNIQUE STRING` in, and grep for that.

Comment: @Sneftel, I see. Yes's that's also an option.